# How to compare two numbers using wildcard in generics in java?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I am trying to compare two numbers using 'wildcard' in generics in java. But getting compile time error. Here is some code :

In this I am trying to compare the two numbers using wildcard and generics.

[image]

I have used wildcard and generics concept to solve the problem but getting error.

Comment: Please read: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: `boolean comp(mygenerics<T> b)`. It doesn't make sense to compare to another instance of a different type. Also, why define your own "comp" method instead of just making `mygenerics` implement `Comparable`?